# How do I delete a server template? (Discord python)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Here is what I have, thanks.

```
@slash.slash(description="Delete your template save")
async def del(ctx):
  guild=ctx.guild
  await guild.??
  await ctx.send(f"{emoji} | I have deleted the server template.")
```

Comment: What is it about? What do you want? Are you facing any errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of a guild's templates using `await guild.templates()`, [as stated in the docs.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=templates#discord.Guild.templates)

Which returns a List of [templates](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Template)

You can do something like this

```py
for template in await guild.templates():
   await template.delete()
```

## THIS DELETES ALL TEMPLATES IN THE GUILD